# Clearing AVPlayer Cache

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, avasset, avplayeritem

1) I am streaming videos on the player from server. Each time playing the video on app increases the app memory. So if I watch the video for 10 times, 10times the size of video is increased in app memory. Am using AVPlayer for this.

2) Stop Streaming - Say I start watching the video and stop it after few seconds. I noticed that entire video is download even after I stop the video. I cancelled loading AVAsset, cleared AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem. Still it streams in the background.